# Css: Mysterious margin

Tags: html, css, web, margin, padding

Does anyone know why this mysterious margin is?
[This is the link to my site](http://znanje.uphero.com/)

I have tried everything! Turning all the margins off and on and playing with padding 
but i just cant find the problem why does horizontal slider bar appear?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Try removing the script that appears after your closing `</html>` element

Comment: I cant its not my work. Its added by my hosting service 000webhosting

Comment: due to the fact that in browsers default styles are different  there is a practice to use reset.css http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a pretty significant typo in [your css](http://znanje.uphero.com/style/fg_membersite.css):

```
body{
    marign: 0px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

*margin* is spelled incorrectly.

To eliminate some odd margins that arise, I would suggest adding this to your code:

```
body {
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Usually a pretty safe bet that eliminates some unnecessary margins, and fixes your problem. I get that you have some margins all over the place, but from your post it's *hard for us* to understand *which* margins you are trying to eliminate.

Comment: That did the job! Thanks! I was writing the body margins at 6 am and i was very sleepy didnt even see that. I will give you the answer after the 6 minutes thing is up

Comment: @RaslavM Glad I could help. It's 5am here as I just found this, we all work on different schedules ;)

Answer (score 1):

it's on **fg_membersite.css line 5** :

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

change to this :

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}
```

Comment: Yes but how do i push my content down then? And also it does not fix the error

Comment: remove body width and height style

Comment: Nop jdero was right if you look close you can see that i misspelled margin in the body tag

Answer (score 1):

use this code :

```
body {
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   margin-left: 0px;
}
```

probably may help you

Answer (score 0):

```
.ads {
width: 160px;
height: 600px;
background-color: orange;
float: right;
}
.content {
margin-top: 50px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: again margin was misspelled wrong in the body tag but ty for help anyway

Answer (score 0):

What I always do to prevent this kind of margin/padding:

```
* {
padding:0;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

It just gives every element standard 0 margin and padding, unless you change it per element of course.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the "body {marign...}" typo as jdero said and your horizontal bar will be gone. You don't need to set all the margin-top, bottom etc to 0 though. Once you fix the typo you will have body {margin : 0px}. This is all you need to set them all to 0.